# How to determine what is causing I/O in tempdb?

Tags: sql-server

We've been running some performance queries against a SQL Server database.

One of these is returning some very concerning results:

```
WITH Aggregate_IO_Statistics
AS
(
    SELECT 
        DB_NAME(database_id) AS [Database Name],
        CAST(SUM(num_of_bytes_read + num_of_bytes_written)/1048576 AS DECIMAL(12, 2)) AS io_in_mb
    FROM sys.dm_io_virtual_file_stats(NULL, NULL) AS [DM_IO_STATS]
    GROUP BY database_id
)
SELECT 
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY io_in_mb DESC) AS [I/O Rank], 
    [Database Name], 
    io_in_mb AS [Total I/O (MB)],
    CAST(io_in_mb/ SUM(io_in_mb) OVER() * 100.0 AS DECIMAL(5,2)) AS [I/O Percent]
FROM Aggregate_IO_Statistics
ORDER BY [I/O Rank]
;
```

What we're getting:

```
I/O Rank    Database Name    Total I/O (MB)    I/O Percent
1           tempdb           94288973.00       88.84
```

Almost 90% of our I/O is being done to the tempdb database. The second rank comes in at only 2.43%.

We're at a loss as to what could be causing all that I/O to tempdb.

Does anyone have any way for us to track down just what is going on in tempdb?

Comment: Are there lots of temp tables? `select * from tempdb.sys.objects` should show give you some insight.

Comment: Maybe the profiler could give a hint, like the SORT WARNINGS event?